# Style icon Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, material-design

I create the application with **NavigationDrawerFragment**, use material design.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBDE7.png

How to make a style icon as in this screenshot?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/97Pie.png

how to make the icon material design?

Answer (score 2):

If you use `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle` instead of `android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle`, you should get the proper styling and behavior.